# Deciding bound on Tensor Rank for a fixed value

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, tensor-rank

This question is related to a previous unanswered [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7903/complexity-of-tensor-rank-over-an-infinite-field) of mine.  Please see that question for background.

When Håstad [proved](http://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/tensorrank.pdf) that computing tensor rank is NP-complete, the rank in question was allowed to be part of the input.  Specifically, given a Boolean formula with $n$ variables and $m$ clauses, Håstad constructed a tensor that has rank exactly $4n+2m$ if the formula is satisfiable and has some larger rank otherwise.

What if we fix the bound on the rank to some constant?  For example...

> What is the complexity of deciding if a tensor has rank at most 3?

The tensor should be defined over an infinite field, otherwise the problem is trivial (...only a finite number of things to check).  Answers for the natural infinite fields $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{C}$ would be best.  I am personally interested in this question using the complex numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Testing for constant *border*-rank can be done in polynomial-time, I'm pretty sure, if you're talking about tensors of fixed arity. More precisely, testing for border-rank $\leq r$ in $\mathbb{C}^{d_1} \otimes \dotsb \otimes \mathbb{C}^{d_k}$ can be done in something like $k(d_1 d_2 \dotsb d_k)^{2(r+1)}$ evaluations of $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ determinants plus some additional <s>constant work (constant depending on $r$).</s> Update 2022-02-10: work of order $f(r) \cdot \prod_{i} \binom{d_i}{r}$, so for $k,r$ constant, this is still polynomial in the $\{d_i\}$.

Theorem 3.7.1.1 of [Landsberg's tensor book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821869078) ("Inheritance") says that the equations for the variety of tensors of border-rank $\leq r$ in $\mathbb{C}^{d_1} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{d_2} \otimes \dotsb \otimes \mathbb{C}^{d_k}$ are given by the equations for border-rank $r$ in $\mathbb{C}^r \otimes \mathbb{C}^r \otimes \dotsb \otimes \mathbb{C}^r$ (Update 2022-02-10: applied by choosing $r$ out of the $d_i$ coordinates in all possible ways) together with all $(r+1) \times (r+1)$ minors of flattenings. Since $r = O(1)$, there are only <s>finitely</s> polynomially many equations of the former type.

Border-rank 1 = rank 1, and more generally rank $\leq r$ implies border-rank $\leq r$. But border-rank 2 can have rank anywhere from $2$ to the arity $k$, and border-rank $3$ in arity 3 can have ranks 3, 4, or 5. Beyond that I don't know about testing for rank.

Comment: Yes, fixed arity.  This book looks great.  The naive system of polynomial equations to check for rank at most $r$ (for arity $k$ and $d = d_1 = \dotsb d_k$) has $d r$ variables in $d^k$ equations, each of degree $k$ with $r$ monomials.  Are the equations for the variety of tensors of border-rank $\le r$ significantly simpler than this?

Comment: If you're talking about the naive equations you get by expressing a variable rank-r tensor and then setting it = to your tensor $T$, then there's a key difference. In that setting, you setup a system of equations that depend on $T$, and then check if the system has a solution. In the equations for border-rank I was talking about, you simply plug the coordinates of your tensor into the equations and make sure they all evaluate to zero. For fixed $r$ and $k$, the only equations that aren't of O(1) size are determinants, so are easy to evaluate.

Comment: Note: checking if a system of equations over $\mathbb{Z}$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ is in PSPACE unconditionally and in PH assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis. In the Blum-Shub-Smale model (or even the usual Boolean model, if working over finite fields), solving systems of equations is NP-complete. So this seems much harder than merely evaluating equations, as in the case of border-rank.

Comment: For others reading this question, the [first two chapters of Landsberg's book](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~jml/Tbookintro.pdf) are available online.

Comment: Oh, the "naive system of polynomials" I spoke about in my first comment is for checking symmetric (aka Waring) rank.